# Python zipfile library fix

Tags: python, passwords, python-zipfile

I've got a problem. I've made a simple zip file with password 12345.
Now, when I try to extract the password using brute-force, zipfile chooses wrong password. It says it found password aaln0, but the extracted file is completly empty. Is there a way to 'fix' the library? Or is there a replacement for it? Thanks

Program code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import threading
import argparse
import time
import zipfile
import string
global found
found = False

def extract_zip(zFile, password):
    """
    Extract archive with password
    """
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        write("[+] Password found:", password, "\n")
        global found
        found = True
    except Exception, e:
        pass

def write(*args):
    print "[%s] %s" % (time.ctime(), " ".join(args))

def main_loop(zFile, length):
    """
    Main loop
    """
    write("[*] Python Brute-Force zip cracker")
    write("[*] Zipfile: %s; password length: %s" % (zFile, length))
    try:
        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zFile)
    except:
        write("Cannot open zip file")
        exit(1)
    for combo in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product(string.letters + string.digits,
                                                            repeat=length)):
        if found:
            break
        thread = threading.Thread(target=extract_zip, args=(zfile, combo))
        thread.start()
    if not found:
        write("[-] Password not found")

def main():
    """
    Main function
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="brute-force-zipcracker.py -f <zipfile> -l <password length>")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--zipfile", help="specify zip file", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--length", type=int, help="password length", default=5)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if (args.zipfile == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)

    main_loop(args.zipfile, args.length)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There's no information in this question what so ever to work with. What "fix" for `zipfile` do you need? What does your code look like, and where does `aaln0` come from?

Comment: @Torxed, as I said, I am using brute-force. I am generating all avaible combinations with length of 5 and then trying to open the zip with these passwords. Password for the zip file is `12345`, but the program says the password is `aaln0`. I added the code

Comment: Not getting an exception means the decompressor had no problems working with the decrypted data. It can still be wrong data.

Comment: @JanneKarila, I know. But I am asking: is there a way to prevent `zipfile` from selecting the wrong password?

Comment: One thing you could do is to check the size of the decompressed file against the zip directory.

Comment: @JanneKarila, How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're doing:

```
for combo in itertools.imap(...):
    if found:
        break
    thread = ...
    thread.start()
if not found:
    ...
```

Just look at it for a second.
`found` is defined in a thread, but you're starting multiple threads and you globally hope that it will be set in one of the threads.
How can you ensure that the correct thread has done the proper job? What if there's a false positive in one of the threads and you don't bother to retrieve the value from each individual thread. Careful with your threads!

Secondly,
if the threads don't finish in time for your `combo` loop you'll end up in `if not found` because the threads haven't finished running yet to find what you're looking for, especially if you have a larger zip-file that takes a few seconds to complete (a successful password would start unzipping the file and it could take minutes, and `found` will not be set until that process is done).

And finally it would be neat to get the parameters used to protect this zip-file.

Edit:

You could also give us more information in the format of:

```
zFile.debug(3)
zFile.testzip()
zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
```

And other useful things from `zipfile.ZipInfo(filename)`

### To the solution then

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import argparse
import zipfile
import string

def extract_zip(filename, password):
    try:
        zFile = zipefile.ZipFile(filename)
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        return True
    except zipfile.BadZipFile:
        return False

def main_loop(filename, length):
    print("[*] Python Brute-Force zip cracker")
    print("[*] Zipfile: %s; password length: %s" % (zFile, length))
    cracked = False
    for combo in itertools.imap(''.join, itertools.product(string.letters + string.digits, repeat=length)):
        cracked = extract_zip(filename, combo)
        if cracked:
            print('Yaay your password is:',combo)
            break
    if not cracked:
        print('Sorry, no luck..')
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="brute-force-zipcracker.py -f <zipfile> -l <password length>")
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--zipfile", help="specify zip file", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--length", type=int, help="password length", default=5)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if (args.zipfile == None):
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)

    main_loop(args.zipfile, args.length)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I should use threading.Semaphore then? Or maybe I'd better not use threads? Also, what do you mean parameters used to protect zip-file? You mean how I've created it? If you need, I can post the zip file

Comment: Yea the zip-file might be useful, if not the parameters used to protect the file-file is enough. for instance `7za a pw.7z *.txt -pSECRET`

Comment: Ok, here is the zip file: http://randomgalaxy.com/stackoverflow/crackme.zip. And I created it using `zip -e crackme.zip dictionary2.txt`. Password is `12345`. P. S. When I tried running your code `zFile.debug(3)`, I got an error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: @Vik2015 I'm almost convinced this is a threading issue. Most likely because you open the file with the `zip.ZipFile()` outside of the thread, then pass that open filehandle into each and every thread and you try to extract it which causes a CRC issue and somewhere along the lines you probably end up with: `Thread#1: CRC fail` + `Thread#2: SUCCESS!!` + `Thread#3: CRC failed` which, overwrites whatever Thread#2 did.. and so on.. Either you do a better thread handling or you simply create some form of unified message board for the thread to check if any other thread has successed in extracting.

Comment: I don't think so... Try to do this in python terminal: `import zipfile; z = zipfile.ZipFile('crackme.zip'); z.extractall('aaln0')`. Again, the real password is `12345`

Comment: I just did, didn't work. + Threading doesn't do you much good on a single-file target anyway, because you'll get a bottleneck on it no matter what, unless you read in the content into a `import StringIO` object and try the extraction process on that instead which would significantly increese your performance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48373/discussion-between-vik2015-and-torxed)